# Is a delegate retained?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I know , the delegate is never retained! Ever!

But can anyone explain me why delegate is never retained ?...

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a memory management thing.

Objective-C works with reference counts to keep the memory clean. This does mean that it can't detect cyclic relationships.

Example:

- Object A owns object B. Object B is retained by object A.
- Object B has a delegate that is object A. Object A is retained by object B.
- Object C owns object A. Object A is retained by object C.
- Object A now has a retainCount of 2, and object B has a retainCount of 1
- Object C gets freed, and releases object A
- Object A and B now have a retainCount of 1, because they own eachother. The system will not free them, because the retainCount is still 1 (still owned by another object)
- Memory leak!

Comment: There is no garbage collector on iOS.  Absolute retain counts are meaningless.

Comment: @bbum There's no collect*or* but there's collect*ion*. Retain counts are used internally by this system, but yes, you shouldn't ever use them in your own code.

Comment: No, there isn't "collection", either.  It is a  pure passive reference counting system.  "Collection" implies some kind of out-of-band processing related to memory management.   The first three sentences don't make any sense when describing memory management on iOS, whether using manual memory management or ARC.   The use of absolute retain counts in the answer isn't correct, either, as the absolute retain counts are meaningless.

Comment: @bbum Reference counting is a form of garbage collection. And I disagree about the counts being meaningless: when they reach zero, the object is freed from the memory. While the developer of an application doesn't ever need to know the number, it's good to know how the reference counter works (retain increases the count, release decreases it, autorelease is a delayed decrease).

Comment: Nowhere did I say that not knowing how reference counts work is unimportant.  It is the absolute retain count that you sprinkle about your answer that is the useless part.   And, no, really, reference counting is not a form of GC.   Never has been.  Nor is ARC a form of GC.  Both Manual retain/release and ARC are just the opposite of GC;  they are passive, manual, memory management schemes.    Call 'em what you like, but realize you are effectively using vocabulary that no one in the community shares commonly.

Comment: This may seem pedantic.  I've seen far too many developers new to the platform make the assumption that Arc or `autorelease` is some form of GC and then have no end of problems when they make all kinds of assumptions about concurrent collections and/or other magical behaviors that don't exist.

Comment: @bbum I just did some reading on the matter and it would indeed appear that my terminology is wrong. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 4):

It's up to you. If you declare it to be retained (`strong` in ARC) it'll be retained.

The rule is to not retain it because it's already retained elsewhere and more important **you'll avoid retain cycles**.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on djromero's answer:

If you have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UITableView`, the controller will be most likely retaining the table and it will be it's delegate / dataSource. If the table retains the delegate / dataSource, then they will be retaining each other and thus never getting released.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea is that the delegate should always outlive the object that assigns it as a delegate. So the webview will be released before the delegate that is assigned.